# Meaning of terms in pivottables: PivotFields, DataFields, PrivotItems, CurrentPage

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I just have some trouble understanding the above terms, anyone can help me with that?

PivotFields, DataFields, PrivotItems, CurrentPage

Also, if I want to change the fields on the filter, which one should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174273%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Changing pivot table report filter:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/566046-changing-pivot-table-report-filter-via-visual-basic-applications-named-range-array.html

Answer (score 0):

Below two links lets get u started

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

http://www.contextures.com/excel-vba-pivot-format-macro.html